# Is there a simple way to have a Bootstrap collapsed navbar expand upwards from a sticky footer (not fixed)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar that I've stuck to the bottom of the viewport as a sticky footer. I don't want to use .navbar-fixed-bottom, as I don't want the navbar footer showing all the time - just when user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

The problem is that when the footer navbar is collapsed on small screens, when clicked to expand it expands downwards - a bit ugly and the user has to scroll down further. Code example here - http://www.bootply.com/SUXJ7xWjSc

Ideally, I'd like the navbar to expand upwards when clicked, much like when .navbar-fixed-bottom is used e.g. http://www.bootply.com/PLBmzQkucC

Try as I might, I've searched high and low for a simple solution but haven't hit one yet. If there's one, I'd love to know, but if it's still on the to-do list for Bootstrap, no problem. Would be nice to have some closure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you have to use your custom styles for the id #btm-navbar

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    #btm-navbar
    {
        background: your-dropdown-menu-bg-color;
        bottom: your-footer-height;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjith, that's a very simple solution! Much better than the status quo. Hopefully this helps other people out too.

Comment: Also, this approach applies nicely when using a static top navbar (.navbar-default or .navbar-top-static) - it solves the problem of menu items pushing page content down when the collapsed menu is accessed. Instead, the expanded dropdown overlays the page content. Thanks again Sanjith!